# get facebook user groups with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-group

ow can I get facebook user group list using javascript ?

I tried with the following code but got empty list.

```
$('#getGroupsButton1').click(function () {
                FB.api(
                    "/me/groups", 
                    function (response) {
                        if (response && !response.error) {
                            /* handle the result */
                            var a = response.data;
                    }
                    }); 
            });
```

Comment: What does the FaceBook API say?

Comment: FB.api is a handle to access FB functions

Comment: Sorry, I meant, have you look at the Facebook documentation? They would normally have answers to things like this. Check their support too.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference-user_managed_groups, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference-user_groups

Comment: @CBroe, I login with {scope: "user_groups"} and still when I FB.api("/me/groups", ... I get empty response.data, any idea why ?

Comment: Did you actually get asked for that permission when you logged in? `user_groups` will be completely removed in October this year, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations – so it doesn’t make much sense to try and build an app that needs it now. You need to make do with `user_managed_groups`, because that is all you can get.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/806001356187097

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your assistance